# Range and DataType attributes on double property not being triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, data-annotations

I have a property in my page model of type double, is required and should be between a specific range. I'm also adding custom error messages. I have defined said property like this:

```
[BindProperty]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "my message")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency, ErrorMessage = "my message")]
[Range(0.00, 999999999.99, ErrorMessage ="my message")]
public double SpecialEquipmentAmount { get; set; }
```

The Razor HTML is simple enough, I think:

```
<input asp-for="SpecialEquipmentAmount" class="form-control" placeholder="$" />
```

When testing, however, if I enter a string value (say, "ASD"), the validation fails as expected, but the error message displays a generic message:

> The value 'ASD' is not valid for SpecialEquipmentAmount.

Instead of my custom message. Neither DataType nor Range attributes seem to be triggered, but rather some hidden validation? Do I need to use another attribute, or how can I override this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm using ASP.NET Core 6. Also, I need to do this validation on the server-side, without doing client-side validations.

Comment: Can you check whether the validation js files are included, most probably through a _ValidationScriptsPartial. Also check the output html generated for the field, whether appropriate "data-" validation attributes are generated.

Comment: @Roy No scripts other than jQuery. Also there are no partials. I checked the HTML output as you suggested and there it is a similar message:

`<input class="form-control" placeholder="$" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SpecialEquipmentAmount must be a number." data-val-range="my message" data-val-range-max="999999999.99" data-val-range-min="0" data-val-required="my message" id="SpecialEquipmentAmount" name="SpecialEquipmentAmount" value="0">`

Comment: Seems the adapters are working as expected, but the unobtrusive js validation files are missing to alert the appropriate message. you could use this 
`
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}`
in your view and check whether the validations are triggered. This works if there is Scripts RenderSection in the layout, else you can directly add the partial to the Layout for the sake of testing.

Comment: @Roy thanks, I'm not sure I understand: do I need other scripts for validations to work? I don't have any javascript referenced other than jQuery, and all validations for the other fields in my page work fine, it's just this particular one.

Comment: @Roy Also, I'm not sure if it matters, but the message found in data-val-number is *not* the one that's being returned, it is similar but slightly different.

Comment: There is https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive, which is based on jquery validation but enhanced to fit all the DataAnnotation Validation provided by Microsoft out of the box. So this is required for the validations to work properly. The validation message you saw might be coming from jquery validation kickin in which need to be suppressed and Microsoft's validation should provide the validation messages.

Comment: @Roy thanks for your reply, but I'm not sure you're understanding my problem. It is not that the validation message is not being shown, it *is* being shown. It's just not showing the message I want it to show. 

Also, regarding your assertion about needing to use the unobtrusive validation for validations to work as a whole, something that boggles my mind is, why the other properties are being validated correctly and the proper messages are shown, if I don't have the unobtrusive library?

Comment: I understand your concern that message is wrong.. its because its not based on the attributes generated by the fields  rather than juery scripts you added which will not take into account all the fields custom created by microsoft for validation. to make use of the fields and show the custom message you need to use the client side scipt created by mmicrosoft for validation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#client-side-validation

Comment: @Roy you say "the juery scripts you added" but I didn't add any script, that's my whole point I'm not using any type of client validation, nor do I want to. Also, why is it working with the other fields?

Comment: From the document you just linked to, it says "Client-side validation avoids an unnecessary round trip to the server when there are input errors on a form. ", doesn't that imply there's a way to do the validation server-side, without needing client libraries and scripts? Which is what I'm looking for (just updated the post to make it clear).

Comment: Then Maybe you can share the full html page generated. Without the JQuery validation the messages wouldnt be shown, From the input tag generated, its not from HTML5 validation also. Either you added jquery or some other bundle like bootstrap which ships with jquery. If you want client side validation based on the data annotations you need to add the unobtrusive validation script provided by microsoft. else you can fall back to solely relying on server side validation which could be achieved by checking ModelState.IsValid which is much more reliable.

Comment: @Roy I appreciate your answers, but you're still not getting what I'm trying to communicate so I'll just stop wasting both our times.

Comment: i'll just drop my 2 cents.. First disable Client side validation if you wish not to get interfered `services.Configure<HtmlHelperOptions>(o => o.ClientValidationEnabled = false);`. In your handler method check model state using `ModelState.IsValid`, when you bind back the model with the error state back to the view and return use `asp-validation-for` or `asp-validation-summary` to view back the error messages in the client side.

Answer (score 0):

At first I guessed it might be a problem with the `[Range]` attribute, so I chose to use `[RegularExpression]`, but the problem persists.

I'm not sure why, but if you want to use custom error message for type mismatch, you can get `ErrorMessage`, remove the original one, and then add custom error message:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors).Where(y => y.Count > 0).ToList();
        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            foreach (var item in error.ToList())
            {

                if (item.ErrorMessage.Contains("is not valid for"))
                {
                    var message = item.ErrorMessage.Split(" ").Last().Replace(".","");
                    ModelState.Remove(message);
                    ModelState.AddModelError(message, "Invalid Error!");
                }
            }
        }
        return Page();
    }
    return Page();
}
```

Of course, I need to remind you that if you do not do some special operations, then you need to set `double` as a nullable type `double?` to verify the `[Required]` attribute, otherwise it will have a default value of `0`.